# So ASP.NET MVC5 Razor Cannot Consume Soap Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, soap, wsdl

I have been scouting the internet for weeks to see how someone has implemented consumption of SOAP Webservices  using mvc razor and most of the samples I have seen are just calculators- adding two numbers or retrieving simple variables from a weather forcast.  The help that people have given usually  do not go beyond adding or creating the wsdl to the application.  I have not seen anyone going beyond this  to guide on setting up controller and views to consume Soap in the MVC pattern.  Can someone tell me in plain language if it is no longer possible to consume SOAP in ASP.NET MVC Razor?  I will not mind a solution that sits only in the view. Or I better look for other alternatives. Is there any recommended book to read?  Any resource on the net that I am missing?. In the absence of any help can one use pure javascript to consume this kind of soap?

```
Name: BBPreQ
Binding: MISPWSBinding
Endpoint: https://mydomain:443/webservices/ispc/index.php
SoapAction: http://mydomain/webservices/ispc/index.php/BBPreQ
Style: rpc
Input:
  use: encoded
  namespace: http://soapinterop.org/
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: BBPreQRequest
  parts:
    wspassword: xsd:string
    address: tns:BBAddress
Output:
  use: encoded
  namespace: http://soapinterop.org/
  encodingStyle: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/
  message: BBPreQResponse
  parts:
    preq_result: tns:PreQResult
Namespace: http://soapinterop.org/
Transport: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
Documentation:
    Gets the result and orderid for the address specified.
    Inputs:  Address mandatory, full Address(street no, street,suburb,town)

    Output:    preq_result

    Errors are returned for:
    5002
    002
```

Can someone use the information above to draft a way to consume this webservice?  My PHP friends tell me this is an easy cake. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you right click on references in your MVC project there's an option to add a Service Reference.  In the Advance section there's even an option to add a Web Reference.  Is this what you're referring to?

Comment: yes I have tried both of them.  In all cases intellisence is seen working but  I never have it working.  When I use the Web Reference it asks me for credentials  which I do not know where that is to be